# jquery wrap circular scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anything besides a Carousel that uses a scroller to wrap? Currently I don't use Carousel because it seems to clog up the site. The JS I use below can only go as far as the div's will allow. What I want is when it reaches the end and the user wants to go back to the beginning, the user doesn't have to click all the way to the left. They can click the right arrow and it will begin again at the first div. I have seen the wrap = circular but I can't seem to apply it here.

JS

```
$(function () {

    var animating = false,
        outerwrap = $(".outerwrapper");

    $("#right, #left").click(function () {
        if (animating) {
            return;
        }
        var dir = (this.id === "right") ? '+=' : '-=';
        animating = true;
        outerwrap.animate({
            scrollLeft: dir + '251'
        }, 1000, function () {
            animating = false;
        });
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="outerwrapper">
   <div class="innerwrapper">
       <div class="prod">
       <div class="prod">
       <div class="prod">
       <div class="prod">
   </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="left" id="left"></div>
    <div class="right" id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a working example in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Give me a second and I can try

Answer (score 0):

I would add a marker on the last element and also add a class to the current element.

Then I'll check to see if the active element has the last class, if it does then animation to `left: 0`

```
JS

$(function () {

    var animating = false,
        outerwrap = $(".outerwrapper");

    $("#right, #left").click(function () {
        if (animating) {
            return;
        }
        var dir = (this.id === "right") ? '+=' : '-=';
        animating = true;

        $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        if($('.active').hasClass('last')){
            outerwrap.animate({
                scrollLeft: 0
            }, 1000, function () {
                animating = false;
            });
        }else{
            outerwrap.addClass('active').animate({
                scrollLeft: dir + '251'
            }, 1000, function () {
                animating = false;
            });
        }
    });

});

HTML

<div class="outerwrapper">
   <div class="innerwrapper">
       <div class="prod active">
       <div class="prod">
       <div class="prod">
       <div class="prod last">
   </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="left" id="left"></div>
    <div class="right" id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Hopefully this makes sense. I haven't tested so good luck :p